# Get Null from Query Out of XML File in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I tried to query product name and product image out of my xml file "favorite.xml" at the start of application, and put it all in the list of favorite product. My query statement is like this

```
 private void Favorite_Load()
        {
            var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            fileName = "Favorite\\favorite.xml";
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, storage))
            {
                lst_product1.Items.Clear();
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(isoStream);

                //Check if there is favorite element in the favorite.xml file
                if (doc.Root.Descendants("favorite").Count() > 0)
                {
                    var data = from query in doc.Descendants("favorite")
                               orderby query.Attribute("id").Value
                               select new ProductsDry
                               {
                                   favID = query.Attribute("id").Value,
                                   favProCate = query.Attribute("cate_xml").Value,
                                   favProId = query.Attribute("pro_id").Value,
                                   favProImage = query.Attribute("pro_image").Value,
                                   favProName = query.Attribute("pro_name").Value

                               };
                    lst_product1.ItemsSource = data; // data=null
                }

                isoStream.Position = 0;
                isoStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Here's my "favorite.xml" file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Favorite's xml-->
<favorites>
  <favorite id="1" pro_id="1" pro_name="Boots Expert Anti-Blemish Cleansing Foam" cate_xml="ProductsOily.xml" pro_image="images/Oily-Dry/BO001.JPG" />
  <favorite id="2" pro_id="3" pro_name="Cerave foaming facial cleanser" cate_xml="ProductsOily.xml" pro_image="images/Oily-Dry/CV001.JPG" />
  <favorite id="3" pro_id="9" pro_name="L'Oreal Paris Go 360 Clean Anti-Breakout Facial Cleanser" cate_xml="ProductsOily.xml" pro_image="images/Oily-Dry/LO003.JPG" />
  <favorite id="4" pro_id="10" pro_name="Olay Foaming Face Wash - Sensitive" cate_xml="ProductsOily.xml" pro_image="images/Oily-Dry/OL014.JPG" />
  <favorite id="5" pro_id="22" pro_name="Alpha Hydrox Sheer Silk Moisturizer SPF 15 Sunscreen " cate_xml="ProductsOily.xml" pro_image="images/Oily-Dry/bp256.1.jpg" />
</favorites>
```

However, after all it doesn't show anything in the list, instead it shows something like the path of the project, and my query is null as I debug it.

[image: How it show on favorite page]

Before, I always use this code to read data and show it from xml file but the xml file is not located in Isoloated Storage. I know this time I read it from Isoloated Storage; therefore, there must be something different. Please help, thanks.

Comment: If data is null then probably your query is wrong. Could you add the XML to the question.

Comment: @venerik Sorry that's incorrect, it's only null because of deferred LINQ execution, his query is fine. It executes only when the listview asks for the data at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things going on here:

1. Your `data` object is null at your breakpoint because `data` is a LINQ query which is only defined, but not yet executed. The query will be executed as soon as something requests it, such as your list view. You can clearly see it working, otherwise you wouldn't see anything on your view. You actually don't need to change anything in that regard but if it bugs you, adding `ToList()` at the end of your query will execute the query at the time of it's definition and `data` will no longer be null.
2. The `ProductsDry` show as a 'path' only because the view doesn't know how to display it and the default representation is `string`. Overiding the `ToString()` function for `ProductsDry` should give you the a `string` representation, but it might not be sufficient if you want to display images or other custom views. For that you have to adjust your list view to display `ProductDry` objects properly.

[1] See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx as a reference for LINQ and deferred execution.

Comment: Thanks, I appended `ToString()` to end of each element selected and `ToList()` at the end of my query like this `favProName = query.Attribute("pro_name").Value.ToString()` and `var data = (from query in doc.Descendants("favorite")
                               orderby query.Attribute("id").Value
                               select new ProductsDry{....}).ToList()`, then I could see the actual value from the debugging mode; however, on the favorite page, it still displays the same thing. Is there any error in my correction here?

Comment: @HouyNarun You misuderstand the use of `ToString()` in this case. What I meant was actually implementing it inside the `ProductsDry` class, see example in the edits above.

Comment: Yes it's work fine, thank you every much for your detail answer :)

Comment: sorry, how can I return all five variables from the select statement above in override `ToString()` ? because I want to use them as well.

Comment: You can append most of them on the same string, except for the image. For that you have to create a custom view for your list view item.

Comment: thanks, would like to ask you one more thing, could you detail a little bit how to display the image in listbox because I need to show the product image with its name in the favorite page. You said I need to custom view for my list; I have no idea to do it. An example would be very fine, Thanks

Comment: That's too long for a comment reply. You could ask it as a new question. Basically, you define a `DataTemplate` of how you want an item to look in your list, then you set the `ItemTemplate` of your list or grid to use the new data template. Here is a guide http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/windows-phone-list-box-with-images

Comment: Thanks your comments I will have a new question post soon related to this